# How to add libsqlite3-dev to yocto kernel for sqlite3 C program

Tags: sqlite, embedded-linux, yocto

I would like to use sqlite3 CLI and sqlite3.h for a C program. I create my own DISTRO conf file as bellow:

```
DISTRO = "mydistro"
DISTRO_NAME = "MyDistro (customized distro)"
DISTRO_VERSION = "1.0"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cli"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " bash"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES .= " ssh-server-openssh"
```

After bitbake the core, I can find sqlite3 CLI in the embedded kernel, but can not find the header files for Sqlite3.  Can any one know how to solve this problem to import the header files ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure about this specific package. But try "IMAGE_INSTALL_APPEND +=" instead of overwriting the variable.

Comment: @ParthibanN this is not overwriting, this is totally correct appending syntax

Comment: @pmod Thanks for pointing. Am not sure about that. But I was using this variable with += always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I really don't need the sqlite3.h in the yocto kernel. I just need to compile the recipe in my host ubuntu. When I bitbake the recipe, I got the warning messages as bellowing:

```
WARNING: cli-0.1-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: cli rdepends on libsqlite3, 
but it isn't a build dependency, missing sqlite3 in DEPENDS or PACKAGECONFIG? [build-deps]
```

Follow the hint, I add the line in my recipe cli_0.1.bb file:

```
DEPENDS = "sqlite3"
```

That solves it.

Comment: BTW, `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "libsqlite3-dev"` does not need also.

Comment: should we have to add "sqlite3" at both places IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "sqlite3"  and DEPENDS = "sqlite3"   ..?